# Make an html range input return to zero on release

Tags: javascript, html, touch-event

I am building a web page to control a moving robot using my iPad. I want to have a slider, probably an html range, to control the direction. By touching the slider to the left or right of the centre the robot will turn, with the radius of turn depending on how far along the slider the touch is. That bit I can do, but I want the slider ( and the turn ) to finish when the touch is lifted. What events are fired when a touch is lifted that I could capture and how would I also make the page work with a mouse?

Thanks

Comment: Can you give us a little code? Right now, your question comes across as a bit vague and unclear without a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the onchange event does just what I want.
So I have the oninput event sending the updates and when the oncnage event is sent I set the velues back to zero